# How can I fix builtins.ValueError: substring not found

Tags: python, python-3.x

[puzzle game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GfuS.png)<- this is the picture.
I get `ValueError` for some inputs. Can anyone help me to fix it, please?

```
def update_letter_view(puzzle: str, view: str, index: int, letter: str) -> str:

>>>"""Return a single character string representing the next view of the 
character at the given index.If the character at that index
of the puzzle matches the guess, then return that character. Otherwise, 
return the character at that index of the view.

>>>update_letter_view('chicken', 'ch^^ken', 2, 'i')
'i'
>>>update_letter_view('banana', 'b^n^n^', 1,'t')
'^'
"""
symbol = '^'
if letter in puzzle:
    return puzzle[puzzle.index(letter, index)]
return symbol
```

Comment: Please show an example of running your code. What inputs cause the ValueError?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice hi I upload a picture at the beginning of my post. it's a demo shows how this code intend to work. the code is actually one part of my whole project. and when I put S(if my puzzle is same in the picture), then I will get ValueError.

Comment: Isn't this just checking if `letter` is at index `index` of `puzzle`? If so, a more intuitive approach would be `if puzzle[index] == letter: return letter`. Checking if the letter is in the puzzle doesn't help anything - just because it exists doesn't mean it is at the right index.

Comment: @Mark What if you pass a wrong index (i.e. index > len(puzzle)) to the function call?

Comment: @HuyVo I didn't mean to say that is the full solution. That would be something like [this](https://repl.it/LtNT). Could use a try-catch block instead or handle the exception outside this function.

Comment: @HuyVo I actually did a similar code as Mark did in the link. it works as intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's have a look at the python `str.index()` method:

`str.index(str, beg=0 end=len(string))`

In your function, `puzzle.index(letter, index)` will find the letter from the position `index`, so it's obvious if `letter` appears before `index`, your code will raises `ValueError`.

How to fix it:

```
def update_letter_view(puzzle, view, index, letter):
    symbol = '^'
    if letter in puzzle and puzzle.index(letter) == index:
        symbol = letter
    return symbol
```

Comment: Did I do that? man I am so sorry actually your code is working as intended. I apology if I did that. It should be a mis-click

Comment: @guanyuma no it was someone else since your account doesn't have the downvote privilege yet

Comment: probably in the 4th line? I am not sure it seems like if the letter occurs before the index it will give a error as well

Comment: @guanyuma can you provide an example that raises the error?

Comment: >>> update_letter_view('chicken', 'ch^^ken', 3, 'i')

Try this one and put the def code you just provided to me.

Comment: @guanyuma maybe there was some mistype in your code, the implementation on my machine works well with your input :)

Comment: Ok, let me check that. Right now I got a new problem. For example if the puzzle is 'apple' and when I guess p how can i let the code shows two p instead of '^p^^^' and if next I guess something else I want to code keep showing the letter p instead of back to '^' this symbol. For example if I guess letter 'c', then it will back to ^^^^^. I know I ask too much but if you can help please help me.

Comment: I fixed the second problem XD

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> string.index(s, sub[, start[, end]])
> ```
>
> Like find() but raise **ValueError** `when the substring is not found`.

This is where your `ValueError` would be occurring. To work around it, use `try/except`.

```
def update_letter_view(puzzle: str, view: str, index: int, letter: str) -> str:
   symbol = '^']

   try:
      if letter in puzzle:
         return puzzle[puzzle.index(letter, index)]
   except:
      #do something else

   return symbol
```

You may argue that you are doing `if letter in puzzle` , so the error should never occur. But your `index(letter,**index**)` changes things, as the **beginning index** from where the search should start may not contain the letter.

**Ex:**

```
   >>> puzzle="abcdef"
   >>> puzzle.index('c')
   =>  2
   >>> puzzle.index('c', 5)                    #beg=5 here
   =>  Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "python", line 1, in <module>
       ValueError: substring not found
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't learned the code except. so I don't know how to do it in your way. But thank you for answering my question, if I know how to do it in your way I am sure it will fix my problem. Thank you bro.

Comment: Um, as I said, use the `try/except` . I even wrote the code snippet. Look it up, helps a lot.

Comment: Sure. Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

`str.index` raises ValueError if it can not find the value you're looking for. If your string is `'orange'` and you look for 'o' after index 2, the `in` test will succeed but the return statement will fail.

Comment: I added a picture shows how this code intend to work. Do you know how should I fix the code to let it work as intended?